# Visual Studio select start up item

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am new to using Visual Studio and I just cloned a repo from GitHub. I now have the repo and I want to run a file "ILPLite.cpp" contained in the repo. When I try to run, I get the message "Select startup item". I not sure how to actually run the code. Do I have to build the project, or maybe import it somewhere ( this what I had to do in eclipse for java projects)?

I read in another question that all my files should have a lock next to them, which they already do. Does someone know how to properly do this, I've been stuck on this for hours.
[image]

Comment: Do you have a *.vc(x)proj or a *.sln file in your folder somewhere?

Comment: @Chris It doesn't. I read somewhere that I need a solution file(?), but the repo didn't contain one

Comment: @Chris. Is there a way to get around that?

Comment: Do you happen to have a link to said GitHub project? Not sure why it would only contain source files but not the solution/project files. I'm also not exactly sure what you mean by get around it; you _need_ a project in order to build a project. But it's a pretty trivial effort to make a project in Visual Studio. I assume (based on the main function that I'm loooking at) that this is some sort of Console Application so what you need to do is File > New > Project and under Visual C++, you would choose **Windows Console Application**. Then give a name to your new project.

Comment: Once you have your project, add all of your source files (which you already have, just add them). You should be able to build it (assuming there aren't any dependency issues based off of whatever is in those other folders).

Comment: Recommend a quick stop over in the Application Wizard while making the project to uncheck precompiled headers. If the repository didn't have stdafx.h or pch.h files, you probably don't want the headaches leaving precompiled headers enabled will bring.

Comment: Does it have  a `CMakeLists.txt` file?

Comment: @CMakeList.txt it does not

Comment: @Chris ok, thanks I will go ahead and try that

Comment: I see there is a makefile Perhaps nmake would work.